# Screenshot of part of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can you make an screenshot of the part of the screen if you press an UIButton?
I've searched a lot for it, but I can't find an answer that works.
Xcode is whole the time complaining, can someone give me a code that works for iOS 6?

Comment: Take a full screen using the standard approach and then crop the resulting image. A quick search on those two separate tasks will give you everything you need.

Comment: I've done that, but it gives whole the time the error : Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration "

Comment: You need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: I've found the solution; changed self.window.layer to self.view.layer

Comment: The resolution of the screenshot is very low, how can I change the resolution to full Retina?

Comment: Are you using a retina display device in Xcode simulator or physically?

Answer (score 1):

I had written this below small class previously. You can make use of it. The latter function gets screenshot of whole screen (and it is obtained from apple's guide, so it is definitely safe). And the first part which I've added, handles different scales (retina or regular). May it help.

```
#import "ScreenshotTaker.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ScreenshotTaker


+(UIImage *) captureRectOfScreen:(CGRect) rect
{
    UIImage *wholeScreen = [ScreenshotTaker screenshot];

    //Add status bar height
    rect.origin.y += UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) ? [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.width : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;

    //NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize([wholeScreen size]));

    CGFloat scale = wholeScreen.scale;

    rect.origin.x *= scale;
    rect.origin.y *= scale;
    rect.size.width *= scale;
    rect.size.height *= scale;

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([wholeScreen CGImage], rect) scale:wholeScreen.scale orientation:wholeScreen.imageOrientation];

    //NSLog(@"Whole Screen Capt :%@ Scale: %f",NSStringFromCGSize([wholeScreen size]), wholeScreen.scale);
    //NSLog(@"Rect to Crop :%@ Cropped :%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect), NSStringFromCGSize([cropped size]));

    return cropped;
}

+(UIImage *) screenshot
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

To capture one particular view:

```
UIView *theView = self.view;
CGSize imageSize = [theView bounds].size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[theView layer] renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You can now save the resulting image or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Do have to make UIView *theView in the .h file?

Comment: @user2291669: ... No, why would you?

Answer (score -3):

You could use this code (not tested):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(USE UR SCREEN PART);
[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:@"yourscreenshot.png" atomically:YES];
```

Just set your screen part infos in the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext brackets.

Comment: what do you mean with USE YOUR SCREEN PART ? And how can I select a part of the view?

Comment: The size of the part you want to screenshot - Like: CGSizeMake(width,height)

Comment: oke but i get this error by [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; It says: Property 'window' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: I created a property, but now its gives the error : " Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration "