# Remove status bar strip from screen capture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I take a screen shot programmatically with the code below it leaves a white strip where the status bar is supposed to be. I know you cannot capture the status bar but I just want the white blank strip cropped out.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)view
{
CALayer *layer = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].layer;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, scale);

[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I duplicate my answer from another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/16067463/837244, it should solve your problems :**

I had written this below small class previously. You can make use of it. The latter function gets screenshot of whole screen (and it is obtained from apple's guide, so it is definitely safe). And the first part which I've added, handles different scales (retina or regular). May it help.

```
#import "ScreenshotTaker.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ScreenshotTaker


+(UIImage *) captureRectOfScreen:(CGRect) rect
{
    UIImage *wholeScreen = [ScreenshotTaker screenshot];

    //Add status bar height
    rect.origin.y += UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) ? [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.width : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;

    //NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize([wholeScreen size]));

    CGFloat scale = wholeScreen.scale;

    rect.origin.x *= scale;
    rect.origin.y *= scale;
    rect.size.width *= scale;
    rect.size.height *= scale;

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([wholeScreen CGImage], rect) scale:wholeScreen.scale orientation:wholeScreen.imageOrientation];

    //NSLog(@"Whole Screen Capt :%@ Scale: %f",NSStringFromCGSize([wholeScreen size]), wholeScreen.scale);
    //NSLog(@"Rect to Crop :%@ Cropped :%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect), NSStringFromCGSize([cropped size]));

    return cropped;
}

+(UIImage *) screenshot
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thats great! Was messing about the cropping sizes, driving me bonkers.